# SharePoint CAML OrderBy Modified does not work

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I have made a query against a list. I want to get the last modified item which meets a certain condition, and my query looks like this:

```
<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef  Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='kortnummer'/><Value Type='String'>kv11</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
```

I get the listitems i need, just not in the right order. Changing Ascending to true does nothing, so obviously there is something with the OrderBy clause that is not right..

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms471093.aspx) it should be possible to order by Modified.

Any idea why my OrderBy does not work?

Comment: can you please post your code to execute that query? maybe you're just sending that additional <Query> tag

Comment: Yeah, because if you get the query wrong, it will return all the results.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me solve it! I had it without <Query> at first but then it didn't return anything at all. Turned out that i just should have changed the datatype of the where fieldref to 'Text' :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always put the OrderBy **after** the Where.

Otherwise you could make sure that you are using the internal name. I usually use SharePoint Manager 2007 to get the internal field names. [Codeplex SharePoint manager](http://www.codeplex.com/spm)

I can see that on a list in my SharePoint, the modified column internal name is "Last_x0020_Modified".

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this in a C# string to get an SPListItemCollection, you don't need "<Query></Query>" tags.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that you fixed it by doing just that! Well, and the FieldRef Value type....